# Blade types for dry cutting pavers, diamond or composite?

Tags: pavers, circular-saw

When are diamond blades worth the extra money, or required?

I've been dry-scoring to 1/3rd thickness different types of pavers for a couple small 20-30sqft projects around the house, using the $2-$3 composite 7" masonry blades from Home Depot in a 'disposable' (but yet to wane or fail) light weight 10 amp $26 Drill Master circular saw from Harbor Freight.

Takes some time and requires rotating through different depth settings, but works fine.  If I were to start a big project, I'd look into a wet saw. But for now, dry cutting next to a 20" box fan is ok.

What would be the advantages of switching to a diamond blade?

Answer (score 1):

Diamond blades aren't that expensive and cut much more quickly. They're much thinner, for one thing. I wouldn't use anything else.

However, doing so with a circular saw won't gain you much. Maneuverability is poor, meaning you're stuck cutting through the material in a big bite. A 7" angle grinder is the ticket. You can slide it back and forth and cut with much more control.

Comment: thinner cut = less dust and quicker cutting. Like that!  But my 2" masonry chisel wouldn't fit in the kerf.  Do you score or cut through?

Comment: I cut through or from both sides to blade depth. Takes about 10 seconds to cut a driveway paver. A tap with a hammer finishes it, and a little cleanup with the wheel knocks down any bumps.

Comment: If I switched to through-cuts from 1/3rd scores, I'd end up creating at least as much dust and the time savings would not be as great. What are the criteria for a good drycut diamond blade?

Comment: You'll have huge amounts of dust regardless, but the time savings will be substantial. Just look for a reputable brand. I bought a basic one from the big box and it has cut dozens of pavers without showing much wear at all.